# Automatically Changing Cell Background Colors Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, colors, cell

So basically I want a code that can change color of cells.
For example, if A1 = 1 and B1 = 3%, 54% or 5% then change B1's background color to green. Else if B1 = 1% or 2% change colors to red.

This is what I have so far, I cant seem to figure it out. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub color()
  Range("A1:B1").Formula = " = If(A1 = 1 AND B1 =3%,Range("A1:B1").Interior.ColorIndex = 4)"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can figure out how the code below works and make necessary changes

```
Sub color()

  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Dim r As Range, c As Range
  Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

  With ws
    Set r = Range("A1").CurrentRegion
  End With

  For Each c In r
    If c.Value = 1 And ((c.Offset(, 1) = 0.03) Or (c.Offset(, 1) = 0.54) Or (c.Offset(, 1) = 0.05)) Then
      Range(c, c.Offset(, 1)).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
    ElseIf c.Value = 1 And ((c.Offset(, 1) = 0.01) Or (c.Offset(, 1) = 0.02)) Then
      Range(c, c.Offset(, 1)).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    End If
  Next

End Sub
```

Comment: When I change the range to ("L2:L7") it stops working, can you please tell me what you think might be wrong?

Comment: Change Set r = Range("A1").CurrentRegion to Set r = Range("L1").CurrentRegion

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is there a way I can change the conditional statement from 1 to a string like c.String = "Good" or something like that.

Comment: yes you have it almost good, just change c.value = 1 to c.value = "Good", in openoffice obasic yes you could cast the cell object to a string but not in vba, the property .value does the cast