# How to give color to a cell in excel programmatically via nodejs code

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have an excel file in which I have few employee details each raw, I insert it as records to my MongoDB and after database operation, I return back the status of MongoDB(like either inserted properly or failed insertion due to some duplication or some other reasons) as success or fail to the excel, I would like to write back to excel success/fail and color my excel cell with green if success and red if fails. Right now I have written back my status messages (success/fail) to excel, but I also need to give either a background color for the cell or write my msg itself in red or green. Attaching my code below. I am using a map in my code to map EmployeeId with the status. Key is the employeeID in one cell of excel for every record. This code is working properly for writing the status to the cell which I have told, but I also need to give color. Can someone help me to solve this?

```
function statusUpdate(){
      const XLSX = require('xlsx');
      let workbook = XLSX.readFile(inputFile);
      let sheetName = workbook.SheetNames[0];
      let worksheet = workbook.Sheets[sheetName];
      var len1=totCount+2;
      for (let [key, value] of myMap) {
        for(var n=2;n<=recordCount+1;n++){
          if(worksheet['V'+ n] == undefined|| worksheet['W'+ n] == undefined){
            worksheet['V'+ n]={}
            worksheet['W'+ n]={}
            worksheet['W'+ m]={}
          }
          if(worksheet['B'+ n].v==key){
              if(value=='Sucess') {

                worksheet['U'+ n].font = {color: {argb:'#FF0000'}};

                worksheet['U'+ n].v =value;
              }
              else{
                worksheet['U'+ n].font = {color: {argb:'#FF0000'}};
                worksheet['U'+ n].v ='Fail';
                worksheet['W'+ n].v = value
                console.log(worksheet['W'+ n].v)
              }
              XLSX.writeFile(workbook,'test.xlsx');
            }
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43527581/2282634

Comment: I am new to nodejs, can someone help me with a snip of node sample

Comment: is there any code formats like worksheet['U'+ n].s where s indicating style or font -- via which we can give some red color for cell

Comment: @Joe, sorry it doesn't. Thankyou